# C++20 modules at scale

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Let's say I have a large codebase that looks something like this:

```
Framework1
  - A.hpp (public, depends on B.hpp), A.cpp
  - B.hpp (private), B.cpp
Framework2
  - ...
...
```

My primary module interface unit would be

```
export module FW1;
export import :A;
import :B;
```

I would then have a module interface partition for A:

```
export module FW1:A;
import :B;
// A stuff using B
```

and a module implementation partition for B:

```
module FW1:B;
// B stuff
```

In my application, I have hundreds of frameworks, each containing dozens/hundreds of classes (some public, some private). Will this approach scale to thousands of partitions? Is this the right way?

Comment: C++20 modules are very young, not sure the best practice have been yet emerged.

Comment: It looks the right approach, that is replacing internally-used header files with module partitions. But likely, you will not find a compiler (or a build tool) which can build everything without errors as modules are still at a very experimental level across all major compiler vendors. E.g. g++-11 has full support but is riddled with bugs. MSVC does not have complete partition support as of yet (I checked sept '21).